# When reading a file through "getline", "\n" is written to the resulting character

Tags: c++, file, getline

When reading a file through `getline`, `\n` is written to the resulting character.
The data in the file is written like this (in this example, `_` represent spaces):

```
2_
c_3_
a_1_
```

The first digit in the file is the number of records.

Code:

```
getline(autorisationFile, temp, ' ');

while (getline(autorisationFile, temp, ' ')) {
        arr[i].login = temp;
        getline(autorisationFile, temp, ' ');
        arr[i].password = temp;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)? It extracts until "_the next available input character is `delim`, as tested by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`, in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to `str`._" In your case `delim` is `' '`, and not `'\n'`, so `'\n'` is extracted, and appended to `str`. Relevant read (possibly duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957080/can-i-use-2-or-more-delimiters-in-c-function-getline

Comment: Maybe, consider nested loops where the outer loop reads a line and uses a `std::istringstream` for the inner loop. Btw. `std::getline()` with `' '` as delim... The formatted input operators (`>>`) use whitespace as delimiter by default (and, btw.² whitespace covers space as well as `'\n'`). So, `std::getline()` might be over-engineered in this case.

Comment: Could you state your question more explicitely please? I'm guessing you want to know how to have the field `password` filled without the `\n` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the way you parse the file a bit...
If you process it *line by line* with `getline` first, and then have `<<` split the line where there are whitespace.

```cpp
while (std::getline(authorisationFile, temp)){
        std::istringstream line(temp);
        line >> arr[i].login;
        line >> arr[i].password;
        i++;
    }
```

[Playground with proof of work](https://godbolt.org/z/MEM8E3) (edited a bit the initial code to work around the missing parts ;) )